# What is this vintage tool?

Tags: hand-tools

I am trying to find out what this vintage tool is called and how it works?
What is the tool for? It was found in coworker's dad basement when he was cleaning up the basement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Dressing wheel for bench grinder stones... used to flatten the stones after they get rounded or grooved.

Comment: And to clean grinder stones that embedded materials like aluminum.